# Rails, how to set root_path as ' '

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-rewrite

For SEO purposes I want the the root_path to be ' '.  In other words, I'd like the canonical homepage URL to be domain.com instead of domain.com/.  I tried to set

```
# routes.rb
get '' => 'home#index', as: :root

# rack_rewrite.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Sendfile, Rack::Rewrite) do
  r301   %r{^/$}, ''
end
```

but this doesn't work.  `rake routes` still shows:

```
root GET    /                home#index
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#config/routes.rb
root "home#index"
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root

Answer (score 0):

In your route file you can add, home -> controller and index --> method

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   root to: "home#index"
   # more routes
end
```